# Mule Datamapper csv lookup - csv file location in grf

Tags: csv, mule, lookup, datamapper, lookup-tables

When doing a datamapper with csv lookup, if I hardcode the path to the csv then it is picking it up. But that is not the right way to do. When i place it under src/main/resources, the csv lookup file comes up in the classes folder - There is no problem during deployment on mule standalone. But during runtime, the file cannot be found. 
Please not I have tried to copy the file in all the classpath locations namely

```
{MULE_HOME}/apps/myapp
{MULE_HOME}/apps/myapp/classes
{MULE_HOME}/apps/myapp/lib
```

Is there something else I need to do ? where else can that be placed ? I tried to edit the grf file ( I know that its not recommended) to include the location using `${mule.env.lookupdir}/mylookup.csv` - the placeholder is not even picked up.

Please let me know if the grf file looks for someother location. or anyother way to tell the grf file to pick up the variable `${mule.env.lookupdir}` from the properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GRF file reference the location fileURL="${app_home}/myfile.csv"

Put your CSV file in the mappings directory of your application.